# jquery How to set a BIND in an iframe window?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQUERY BInding to an iFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950393/jquery-binding-to-an-iframe)

using jQuery how do you set a bind event inside an iframe window?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input', document.iframe1.contentWindow.document).change();
```

where iframe1 is an iframe